# Can't get a futures list from Bybit with CCXT

Tags: python, ccxt, bybit

I'm trying to get a list of all the futures available on Bybit using the CCXT library.

If I use brackets with fetch_futures_markets it says I'm a parameter short.

```
import ccxt

exchange = ccxt.bybit({
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'apiKey': config.BYBIT_API_KEY_DYNAMIC_BOOK, 
    'secret': config.BYBIT_SECRET_KEY_DYNAMIC_BOOK
                       })

markets = exchange.fetch_future_markets()
```

```
TypeError: bybit.fetch_future_markets() missing 1 required positional argument: 'params'
```

And without the () I get an empty list.

```
import ccxt

exchange = ccxt.bybit({
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'apiKey': config.BYBIT_API_KEY_DYNAMIC_BOOK, 
    'secret': config.BYBIT_SECRET_KEY_DYNAMIC_BOOK
                       })

markets = exchange.fetch_future_markets
```

I've tried adding futures to the exchange params, still no joy.

```
 exchange = ccxt.bybit({
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'apiKey': config.BYBIT_API_KEY_DYNAMIC_BOOK, 
    'secret': config.BYBIT_SECRET_KEY_DYNAMIC_BOOK,
    'options': {'defaultType': 'future' }
                       })

markets = exchange.fetch_future_markets()
```

I'm new at this, both StackOverflow and coding. So excuse me if I make obvious mistakes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch_future_markets()` has been deprecated. You have to pass future markets as an option.

```py
import ccxt

exchange = ccxt.bybit({
    'apiKey': config.BYBIT_API_KEY_DYNAMIC_BOOK,
    'secret': config.BYBIT_SECRET_KEY_DYNAMIC_BOOK,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'options': {
        'defaultType': 'future',
    },
})

exchange.load_markets()
```

Comment: Solved it. Thank you very much.